# Hibernate schema validation fails at Microsoft SQL Azure

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, azure-sql-database

I would like JPA application to validate schema during start. For this reason I added the following property to `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

However hibernate fails to validate schema:

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing table metadata
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:938)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:26)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2907)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2912)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setCatalog(SQLServerConnection.java:3227)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.switchCatalogs(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:342)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetFromStoredProc(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:296)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetWithProvidedColumnNames(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:318)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getTables(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingDatabaseMetaData.getTables(DelegatingDatabaseMetaData.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
    ... 50 more
```

Is there any workaround except disable validation?

Answer (score -2):

It's seems to there is syantx error in SQL file. Some time the SQL might get different from database to database, and the other another database not compitable for the sql syntax you using.